# scheme getting unbound when trying to call function

Tags: scheme

The below is a calculator designation in scheme. And I am getting `unbound variable` error when I call `fouroperatorcalculator` or `calculator`

```
(define (twoOperatorCalculator lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        0
        (if (eqv? '+ (car lst))
            (twoOperatorCalculator (cdr lst))
            (if (eqv? '- (car lst))
                (twoOperatorCalculator (cons (-(cadr lst)) (cddr lst)))
                (+ (car lst)
                (twoOperatorCalculator (cdr lst)))))))
(define (fouroperatorcalculator lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
    lst
        (if (eqv? '/ (cadr lst))
        (fouroperatorcalculator (cons (/ (car lst) (caddr lst)) (cdddr lst)))
            (if (eqv? '* (cadr lst))
            (fouroperatorcalculator (cons (* (car lst) (caddr lst)) (cdddr lst)))
            (cons (car lst) (fouroperatorcalculator (cdr lst)))))))
(define (Nested x)
    (if (pair? x)
    (twooperatorcalculator(fouroperatorcalculator (calculatorNested x)))
    x))
(define (calculatorNested lst)(map Nested lst))
(define (checkoperators lst)
    (if (null? lst)
    #f
    (if (and (number? (car lst)) (null? (cdr lst)))
    #t
    (if (and (pair? (car lst)) (null? (cdr lst)))
    (checkoperators (car lst))
    (if (and (number? (car lst)) (or (eqv? '- (cadr lst)) (eqv? '+ (cadr lst)) (eqv? '/ (cadr lst)) (eqv? '* (cadr lst))))
    (checkoperators (cddr lst))
    (if (and (pair? (car lst))   (or (eqv? '- (cadr lst)) (eqv? '+ (cadr lst)) (eqv? '/ (cadr lst)) (eqv? '* (cadr lst))))
    (and (checkoperators (car lst)) (checkoperators (cddr lst)))
    #f))))))

(define (calculator lst)
    (if (checkoperators lst)
    (twooperatorcalculator (fouroperatorcalculator (calculatornested lst)))
    #f))
```

Here when I call this `(fourOperatorCalculator '(5 / 2 * 2))` I get

```
*** ERROR: unbound variable: fourOperatorCalculator
    While loading "./jdoodle.sc" at line 41
```

Same with `calculator`, I tried to change parantheses and everything but didn't work. Please help me fix my problem.

Comment: In the posted code, `fouroperatorcalculator` is defined, but not `fourOperatorCalculator`. Scheme has been case-sensitive since R6RS. It is bad style in general to be inconsistent in naming (`twoOperatorCalculator` and `fouroperatorcalculator` above), and bad style in Scheme to use camelCase. Use kebab-case: `two-operator-calculator` and `four-operator-calculator`. This is much easier to read, and consequently, easier to get right when you call your new procedures.

Comment: The same problem occurs again in the definition of `calculator`, which calls the procedure `twooperatorcalculator`. But `twooperatorcalculator` has not been defined; `twoOperatorCalculator` was defined. These are just typos.

Comment: Usually Scheme programmers avoid this by using only lisp-case / kebab-case with all lower case identifiers. You should try it and you won't get these kind of silly bugs :-)